# apache: can't renew ssl certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl

I have Godaddy SSL certificate for one website on my dedicated server running Centos 5.3 / Apache 2.2.3. I have renewed certificate on Godaddy recently, however now it's showing as expired on my website. I've re-keyed certificate since and reuploaded domain.key, domain.crt and bundle.crt (example file names) files to the server, restarted apache, but the sertificate still shows as expired. I'm running out of clues.

I've tried replacing content of .crt files with jiberish and restart apache - it's still showing that certificate is expired, even though it shouldn't be picked up at all. I eventually rebooted dedicated server, still no luck. I'm using free SSL check tool http://www.digicert.com/help/ which clearly shows all the green checks except one - certificate is expired. Has someone any idea what might be causing this? Could there be some kind of caching going on here?

UPDATE: after running

```
openssl x509 -in domain.crt -noout -enddate
```

I'm getting this output:

```
notAfter=Jun  2 08:16:51 2013 GMT
```

So I asume this means I have the right certificate on the server and yet the old expired one shows on the web...

SOLVED: I did't mention this before, but it appears that the old certificate was hanging on Plesk, which was not used to create it in the first place, thus never looked at.

Comment: I would heed ErikA's answer.  Go into /etc/httpd (or whatever the Apache root is) and do something like `grep -r -i ssl *` just to find every config that mentions ssl.  At this point, it really does sound like your Apache is pointing at the wrong cert.

Comment: I already did that, went through every possible conf file and nothing. I've "used openssl x509 -in domain.crt -noout -enddate" which confirmed that correct certificate is on the server

Comment: Heh, are you looking at the right Apache instance?  There's no proxy, etc.?  As you've described the configuration and the file as being correct, I may look elsewhere.  `apachectl -S` shows the right thing?

Comment: At this point I'd say "If you stop apache, does it still say the certificate is expired" (the site is being hosted by some other server)?

Comment: It's definitely the right server and right instance of Apache. I've tried stopping, restarting Apache, even restarting server itself, DNS checks, everything there is on the book. I'm afraid this is a dead end for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by Plesk, which wasn't used for ages and thus never considered a part of the issue, however it somehow managed to override my manually added SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Just to double-check, you could run

openssl x509 -in domain.crt -noout -enddate

against your certificate file on the server. I'd also check for correct dns resolution on your client. Also check your local host file for old entries.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm getting "notAfter=Jun  2 08:16:51 2013 GMT" which I asume means that I have the right certificate on the server? My local hosts file is clean. I don't quite understand what you mean by "correct dns resolution", I mean if there was a problem with DNS wouldn't the website be down all together?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no caching going on. In short, you're not putting the new certs in the correct location. You need to look through your *entire* Apache config and find the correct location for your cert.

Comment: But I haven't even changed file locations, not even names. I've searched entire server for other possibe .crt files and came up with nothing. I have no idea where apache is pulling that old data from. I went through every single apache conf file and also there is nothing else that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flexibility, I would try setting the loglevel for mod_ssl to a nice, decent level and see if you can't walk the steps Apache is taking as it starts.

You can setup dedicated mod_ssl logging as explained here:

http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_reference.html#ToC20

Comment: I have that running already, nothing useful whatsoever.